# Changing <td> <i> CSS based on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been asked to implement a small validation on values and if the values are greater or less than 0 i need to change or add/remove the css for the td and i tag

My table looks something like this

```
        <table class="table table-hover" id="studentweek">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th">Weeks</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>VAR (%)</td>
                    <td class="text-warning"> <i class="classname">-10.65%</i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>VAR (diff)</td>
                    <td class="text-warning"> <i class="classname">-13,953</i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>VAR (%)</td>
                    <td class="text-navy"> <i class="classname">8.81%</i></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>VAR (diff)</td>
                    <td class="text-navy"> <i class="classname">11,320</i></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

currently i am hard coding the css but i would like to be able to dynamicly change these as the values change automatically, can someone suggest the best way to archive this?

i was thinking in my Ajax request to do something like this:

```
var sdlyvar = $(parseFloat(".classname").text());

if (sdlyvar < 0){
    $('.classname').removeClass(".classname").addClass("fa-level-down");
} else {
    $('.classname').removeClass(".classname").addClass("fa-level-up");
}
```

Comment: `text()` will return `-10.65%`..You can not really compare this string with Number(`0`)

Comment: so i should be using .val() ?

Comment: @GawaiHau No, you should use `parseFloat` on `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here [.slice](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) will remove the % sign in this code and the rest of the code will compare the value and assign or remove class

```
var sdlyvar = $('#sdlyvar').text();   

if (sdlyvar.slice(0,-1) < 0){
    $('#sdlyvar').removeClass("fa-level-up");
    $('#sdlyvar').addClass("fa-level-down");
} else {
    $('#sdlyvar').removeClass("fa-level-down");
    $('#sdlyvar').addClass("fa-level-up");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript parseFloat for parsing percentage (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp).

```
var percent = $('#sdlyvar').text();
var result = parseFloat(percent) / 100.0;

if (result < 0){
    $('#sdlyvar').removeClass("fa-level-up");
    $('#sdlyvar').addClass("fa-level-down")
} else {
    $('#sdlyvar').removeClass("fa-level-down");
    $('#sdlyvar').addClass("fa-level-up")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you can't compare a string like `"-10.95%"` with an integer, because of the final `%` symbol. You have to use `parseFloat` on tha value:

```
var sdlyvar = parseFloat($('#sdlyvar').text());
```

It will take care of all the non-numeric stuff after the number.

Then, you'd probably want to remove the opposite class when updating:

```
if (sdlyvar < 0){
    $('#sdlyvar').removeClass("fa-level-up").addClass("fa-level-down");
} else {
    $('#sdlyvar').removeClass("fa-level-down").addClass("fa-level-up");
}
```

A few random suggestions:

1. Make clear what's wrong in your code when posting on StackOverflow
2. When referring an element more than once with jQuery, consider putting the selection in a variable, like `var $sdlyvar = $("sdlyvar");`: faster to type and execute.
3. Save us some whitespaces when posting code :/

Comment: Thank you, this seems to do it as does the other 2 anwsers. however i am over 5 tables like this, i would have to repeat this 4x for 1 table is this the best practice? i will also take note to the suggestions :) sorry my first post.

Comment: @GawaiHau The best practice is to write your code once, of course. I suggest giving your elements a semantic class when they have the same purpose, like `student-year-diff` or something, and use those to select your elements.

Comment: Hi @MaxArt i have updated my original post am i on the right lines of doing it via a class so its more generic? thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @GawaiHau Don't alter your question, or whoever will see this post won't understand what's going on :/ You're free to open another question, though. Anyway, I suggest using a more semantic term than `classname`. Also, you'll have to iterate through your elements using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score -1):

```
var lis=document.querySelectorAll("tr td i");
for(var i in lis){
    if(parseInt(lis[i].innerHTML)<0){
    lis[i].className+=" fa-level-down";
  }
  else{
        lis[i].className+=" fa-level-up";
  }
}
```

Comment: ... that doesn't work. First of all, it's `className`, then why do you want to give a pure JS answer when OP is clearly using jQuery?